# Unable to edit data on the same view page laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to update the business hour on the same page. There are other answer that I review in the stackoverflow but I still cannot manage. Help really appreciated.

Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hour extends Model
{
    public $table = 'biz_hour';
    protected $primaryKey = 'day_id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'day_id', 'day_name', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'day_off'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, Hour $biz_hour)
    {
        
        $request->validate([
            'start_time' => 'required',
        ]);
    
        $start_time = \App\Models\Hour::find($biz_hour);
    
        ['start_time' => $request->start_time];
        foreach($biz_hour as $biz_hour){
        $start_time->save();
        }
        return redirect('start_time');

        //$biz_hour->update($request->all());
        //return redirect()->route('biz_hour.index');
    }
```

Biz_hour.blade.php

```
<div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead class="text-uppercase">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">Day</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                                    <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                                    <th scope="col">is Day off?</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @foreach($biz_hour as $biz_hour)
                            <form action="{{ route('biz_hour.update',$biz_hour->day_id) }}" method="POST">
                                @csrf
                                @method('PUT')
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row"><br>{{$biz_hour->day_name}}</th>
                                    <td><div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="time" value={{ Carbon::parse($biz_hour->start_time)->format('h:i') }} name="start_time"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><div class="form-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="time" value={{$biz_hour->end_time}} name="end_time"></div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><br><label class="switch">
                                        <input type="checkbox">
                                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                                      </label></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="main-content-inner">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mt-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" name="upload">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

After clicking save button, the page only refresh but the data is not sent to the database. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update is not done because you actually didn't assign the new start_time for the start_time you wanted to update.
Try this

```
public function update(Request $request, Hour $biz_hour)
{
    
    $request->validate([
        'start_time' => 'required',
    ]);

    $start_time = \App\Models\Hour::find($biz_hour);

    $start_time->start_time => $request->start_time;

    foreach($biz_hour as $biz_hour){
         $start_time->save();
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('status', 'updated');
}
```